# Are certain CSS "class" keywords PrimeFaces-specific?

Tags: css, primefaces, datagrid

**The names behind PrimeFaces' `class` attribute values in the html generated for data grids -- like `ui-paginator-rpp-options` for the rows per page display/input, and `ui-paginator` for the page "navigator" GUI component -- are those names PrimeFaces-specific?** Or could I easily find other UIs that use the same names in the class attribute?

My understanding is those names have been created by PrimeFaces, and there was no other pseudo-standard using those names earlier, right?

I am simply wondering if the code I am writing to address GUI details like these is PrimeFaces-specific or not, which would have consequences for the architecture I am designing for a test framework. It should clearly reflect what refers to (and conceptually depends on) what ;)

I am amazed that after years of wrangling with this stuff, I still am note sure about this. If the answer is so obvious that it embarrasses me too much, I will delete this question (I think :) )

Comment: Many classes in PrimeFaces come from the jquery-ui guidelines. But indeed some are PF specific. If styling needed to be done for components  or component parts that have no counterpart in the jquery-ui set of components. It would indeed have been better if those would not have gotten the ui- prefix, but a pf- prefix.

Comment: Do you know of consise references for keywords used by PF/jquery-ui? I have a hard time finding something useful. 
And why don´t you make an answer of it, this already would qualify for acceptance.

Comment: No, sorry don't have a list. May I ask what the reason is for wanting to know this? I personally never encountered a problem or found it even a little troublesome

Comment: No problem, no troubles. Just trying to avoid future modification. I am writing sourcecode that supports the identification of GUI controls from various applications, mostly (but not exclusively) PrimeFaces-based ones. That source is organized after the principle of loose coupling, and I am simply wondering inhowfar certain class= attribute values are to be seen only in PrimeFaces-based apps so I can avoid dividing the source code in a suboptimal way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many classes in PrimeFaces come from the jquery-ui guidelines. But indeed some are PF specific. If styling in PrimeFaces needed to be done for components or component parts that have no counterpart in the jquery-ui set of components, they 'invented' new classes. It would indeed have been better if those would not have gotten the ui- prefix, but a pf- prefix.

There is, afaik, not en exaustive list or even a non-exhaustive one that contains an overview of all of these